# How to convert a hexadecimal MSDos date into human readable date format

Tags: c++, wmi

I queried a log file using WMI query langugage through c++.I obtained a Variant date(a decimal number representation of date ) type when retrieving the TimeWritten Property of the log file.I converted the variant date to an DOSDate(an hexadecimal representation of date ) using VariantTimeToDosDateTime function.Now i have an hexadecimal representation of date and need to convert it into a human readable format.
The snippet of my code is :

```
hr = pclsobj->Get(L"TimeWritten",0,&vtProp,0,0); 
    USHORT udate[10];
    USHORT utime[10] ; 
    DOUBLE date = (vtProp.date) ;
    wcout << date << endl ;  
    VariantTimeToDosDateTime(date , udate , utime);
    wcout << udate << " " << utime << endl ; 
    wcout << "TimeWritten : " << vtProp.pdblVal << endl ;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

The output produced is :

```
2.29069e-317
00BFF74C 00BFF730
TimeWritten : 0046BEFC
```

could somebody help me through with this.

**Edited code :**

```
 hr = pclsobj->Get(L"TimeGenerated",0,&vtProp,0,0);
    DOUBLE vgeneratedDate = (vtProp.date);  //reading the variant date as double
    wcout << "date : " << vgeneratedDate << endl ; 
    SYSTEMTIME generatedsysTime ;
    bool converted = VariantTimeToSystemTime(vgeneratedDate , &generatedsysTime); // converting variant date to systemdate
    std::string generateddate ;
    CString cgenerateddate ; 

    cgenerateddate.Format(  "%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d",  // converting systemdate to cstring
                        generatedsysTime.wYear,
                        generatedsysTime.wMonth, 
                        generatedsysTime.wDay,                       
                        generatedsysTime.wHour, 
                        generatedsysTime.wMinute, 
                        generatedsysTime.wSecond,
                        generatedsysTime.wMilliseconds );
    generateddate = cgenerateddate ;    // cstring to c++ string
    cout << "TimeGenerated : " << generateddate << endl ; 
    jstring jgenerateddate = env->NewStringUTF(generateddate.c_str());
    env->CallObjectMethod( mapobj , putMethod , env->NewStringUTF("TimeGenerated") , jgenerateddate );
    VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

Comment: Just use [VariantTimeToSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221440(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of VariantTimeToDosDateTime.

Comment: hi @FloIsAwsm thanks for the response,I tried to make the change as mentioned in the above edited code.But the program is getting trashed when it reaches the line  VariantTimeToSystemTime(date,lpSystemTime).What am i missing

Comment: @D vignesh VariantTimeToSystemTime does not allocate memory for lpSystemTime. Just create a local `SYSTEMTIME` variable and pass it by reference. `SYSTEMTIME sysTime; VariantTimeToSystemTime(date, &sysTime);`

Comment: @FloIsAwsm can i print the sysTime with cout or should i Convert it to some other in order to print

Comment: It might help to read some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Comment: That Worked.It helped a lot and thanks @FloIsAwsm

Comment: hi @FloIsAwsm , i converted the double valued variant time to human readable time.But all the values that i get is "1899-12-30 00:00:00.000",

Comment: I have added the code snippet above and what is the mistake that i am making

Comment: @D vignesh Can you tell me where vtProp comes form and what it is.

Comment: @FloIsAwsm Thanks for the response.i solved the problem.Variant is an instance of the VARIANT type.just converting the vtProp into a string solved the problem.